Peculiar pattern of errors in series RLC quality factor
I performed an experiment to study the behaviour of a series RLC circuit at and near the resonant frequency. I did it 3 times, with 100 Ω, 200 Ω and 300 Ω, with the same L and C values. For each case, I plotted the graph between power and frequency, and calculated Q-factor using the following formula:
$$ Q = \frac{f_0}{\Delta f} $$
where I got the required frequencies from the graph.
Then I calculated Q-factor using the formula
$$ Q = \frac{1}{R} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$
and then I calculated the error in my experimental value vs. the theoretical value. I noticed that my error reduced significantly as I increase the resistance from 100 to 300 Ω. My professor said there's a good reason behind it. What is it?
Thanks in advance.

Please, stop asking ChatGPT about technical engineering questions. Unless you know the subject well enough to quality check the output of the text generator, the answer is worse than no answer. It is extremely good at "sounding" convincing, but it does not "know" anything and the answer might be wildly wrong and you are none the wiser. Ergo worse off than when you knew you didn't know anything!

Did you measure DCR of L? or estimate DCR/L ratio?

Nope, we were told to assume ideal reactive components.
This is a first year physics lab, BTW :)

What was value of L?  and dimensions

What was the generator, do you have a spec sheet? What was its voltage in each case, compared to the voltage on the L/C?

We only measured the voltage across the resistor to calculate average power using $V^2/R$. I don't have info about the hardware. My professor is looking for a theoretical answer, not related to the specific hardware of the experiment.

Do you know where all the resistance is besides the resistor?  Everything has resistance. Some parts like Caps , its just really small rated as a % dissipation factor (DF) at 120 Hz (2x60 = std)  or ESR for high freq. ... so not there.  Answer ?

ChatGPT can make any false answer sound correct, although it gave you a good hint. (there is  a lot of bad info on the web it had to learn)

R must include Rs of generator = 50 and DCR of L using a DMM.

So is the reason just the fact that as the R i used (just of the resistor) gets larger, the fact that I didn't account for DCR of L and R of generator becomes less significant?

If you add 50 to 100 + DCR , what is the new Q?

So what is the correct equation? now that you understand

Okay adding 50 + DCR gets it closer to the value I got experimentally from the graph!

If L is large estimate its value to get the correct Q in each case by solving for R.  Your task is to write the accurate equation for R to get the correct Q with DCR and Rs.
